# How do I interpret the server name, instance name, and the name in the SSMS browser?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have this screen shot showing how I am logged in and showing the output of two select statements. I see the server name and instance name but what is the name in the browser tree at left? " SQLSERVERINSTAN " is the name of the computer that I gave when I installed the O/S. What is the difference between the Server Name at right, from the SELECT @@servername command, and the name of the computer?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the name of the SQL Server instance.

You have named it when you installed SQL-Server.

You can have more than one instance in the same server.

Comment: Still confused.

Comment: Every instance can be considered a single server. Have a look: https://serverfault.com/questions/11746/what-is-a-sql-server-instance

Answer (score 0):

If you Google these you will find [this reference to @@SERVICENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servicename-transact-sql) tells you this is the registry key under which SQL Server is running. Similarly [this reference to @@SERVERNAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servername-transact-sql) tells you that this is the name of the local server that is running SQL Server. So the server name is the unique name of this SQL server instance on your computer.

`SQLSERVERINSTAN` is the name of the Windows server on which the SQL Server is installed. If you have a named instance of the server, or more than one SQL server installed, then the instance name is used to identify which SQL Server you are addressing. I have two SQL Servers installed on my development instance; one as a copy of the production server and one as a development server. Each has a different instance name.